# Zend Framework 2 How to use multiple Modules?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a question about the Zend Framework 2. I want to implement more than one Modules. But the view of the last Module (In this case "Home"), is displayed. I dont know why. 
Maybe someone can help me here

My application.config.php

```
'modules' => array(
    "Login",
    "Home",
),
```

Everytime the "Home"-View is displayed. But i want the Login-View displayed. The Controller of LoginController is called.

Comment: how have you defined your view manager? are you setting view models template in action ? how have you defined your invokable controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the template map is configured properly in your module.config.php. In this example the template has the configs for both modules, however you could also have a module.config.php for each module if you so desired, with its template_map pertaining only to the controllers within that specific module.

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map'             => array(
        'Login/some_controller/index' => __DIR__ . '/path/to/view/file', 
        'Home/some_controller/index'  => __DIR__ . '/path/to/view/file'
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
)
```

Now your controller invokables

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Home\Controller\Index' => 'Home\Controller\IndexController',
        'Login\Controller\Ajax' => 'Application\Controller\AjaxController',
    )
 )
```